# Let $P_{1},P_{2}$ be orthogonal projectors. With what condition is $P_{1} + P_{2}$ an orthogonal projector and on which space is it projecting?

Tags: vector-spaces, projection

> Let $P_{1},P_{2}$ be orthogonal projectors on finite unitary space. With what condition is $P_{1} + P_{2}$ an orthogonal projector and on which space is it projecting?

I have concluded that the condition is $P_{1} * P_{2} = - P_{2} * P_{1}$.
For the space it is projecting, I believe I should observe $Im (P_{1} + P_{2})$ but since $Im (P_{1} + P_{2}) \subseteq Im (P_{1}) + Im(P_{2}) $ I don't see how to conclude anything from there. Any hint helps!

Comment: Note that the images of $P_1$ and $P_2$ mist have null intersection, and that the rank of $p_1+p_2$ must be its trace, which is sum sun of the traces (thus the ranks) of $p_1$ and d $p_2$, so the image of $p_1+p_2$ must be the sum of the images of $p_1$ and $p_2$. In other words: $p_1(p_1(y)+p_2(z))+p_2(p_1(y)+p_2(z))$ must always equal $p_1(y)+p_2(z)$, which entails $p_1 \circ p_2=p_2 \circ p_1=0$.

Comment: @Mindlack can you explain further why do images of $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ have only null intersection? I don't know if the text of the task is misleading, but $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ are not mutually orthogonal, they are orthogonal projectors. Am I missing something obvious? I am kind of beginner in this scope.

Comment: If $x$ is in the image of $P_1$ and $P_2$, then $(P_1+P_2)(x)=2x$. This is impossible when $P_1+P_2$ is a projector, unless $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $P_1+P_2$ will always be self adjoint. Hence $P_1+P_2$ is a projection precisely when $(P_1+P_2)^2=P_1+P_2$, which occurs precisely when $P_1 P_2=-P_2 P_1$ (1). If this equality holds note that we can rewrite the operator $-P_1P_2P_1P_2$ as $-(-P_2P_1)P_1P_2=P_2P_1P_2$, but we can also rewrite it as $-P_1(-P_1P_2)P_2=P_1P_2$. Hence $P_1P_2=P_2P_1P_2$. Taking adjoints on both sides we get $P_2P_1=P_2P_1P_2$ so we see that actually $P_1P_2=P_2P_1$. In conjunction with (1) this clearly shows that $P_1P_2=P_2P_1=0$ so $P_1H$ and $P_2H$ must be mutually orthogonal subspaces. Conversely, if $P_1H$ and $P_2H$ are mutually orthogonal subspaces it's easy to see that (1) holds (both sides are then $0$).

Comment: Can you explain why does it work when $P_1 P_2=P_2 P_1=0$ precisely? I got that the $P_1 P_2=-P_2 P_1$ and I can not see why it doesn't work.

Comment: You are right, my original argument was far from complete. I've edited now so hopefully this works.